# React app unable to fetch data from Azure SQL backend (Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED)

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-webapi, fetch-api

I hosted a React SPA with ASP.NET Core 5.0.17 App on Azure but it is unable to fetch data from the API. I've also hosted the SQL database on Azure SQL backend and changed the connection strings on the Web App to match it. Why is the React App still unable to fetch data?

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED:
https://freeimage.host/i/h7iI2f

WeatherForecastcontroller API is able to fetch data from hardcoded array: https://freeimage.host/i/h7i91a

This is my Fetch API source URI saved in .env file: https://freeimage.host/i/h7iOEg
https://onboarding2.azurewebsites.net/api/customers

Postman is returning data from API: https://freeimage.host/i/h7ssDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is obvious, it should be that `.env` file does not take effect in SPA.

**Please check this blogs.This article describes in detail how to configure and enable environment variables.**

[Adding environments to ASP.NET Core with React.js SPA](https://www.faesel.com/blog/aspnet-core-react-spa-adding-environments#add-your-build-scripts)